# Executing datafactory pipeline results undocumented 3208 error

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, vnet, azure-data-factory

This issue was already reported in [GitHub](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/50030). We have the same issue and trying my luck in this forum for speedy resolution. Very little technical details are known on this error. This issued showed up in our newly created resourceGroup that has vNet (resourceGrough that doesn't have vNet or SelfHostedRuntime works fine).

Where is the issue Datafactory or Databricks?
We have vNet, Datafactory, SelfHostedRuntime, Databricks (with managed subnets).

We are getting below variant of the same error...

> {
> "errorCode": "3208",
> "message": "An error occurred while sending the request.",
> "failureType": "UserError",
> "target": "process-demo-source-data",
> "details": []
> }

Comment: After little more t-shooting and investigation, the failure was related to Databricks in our vNet (vNet injection, which is essentially letting Microsoft to manage two subnets within our vNet).
The vNet injection is a very well documented feature not sure why its failing! Not having Databricks within in our vNet has a huge implications on security & compliance posture of our product. Can someone please help us to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Data Flows internally uses Azure Databricks. Dataflows helps build orchestration, activity and resource management and then Azure Databricks helps to build compute.

Generally, you will receive this error message for the following reason.

- There is a network connection issue with the  Databricks service.
- Azure Databricks service was interrupted due to any specific outages.

Make sure to subscribe to Azure Databricks service updates:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/status